# how to retrieve hashed password for login php

Tags: php, sql, database

i am trying to build my first login system, i am a beginner.

i want to retrieve a password from my database and use this code to check the login.

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
}
```

the password in the database is hashed using

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

i know i should use sql

```
SELECT password FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email'
```

how do i connect $hash to my sql?

Comment: Are you asking how to store the hash into your mysql table, or do you want to know how to check the given hash against the hash in your mysql table?

Comment: i want to know how i retrieve the hashed password from the database and 'fill' it in the variable $password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so basically to explain how password_verify works:

The first parameter is a non-hashed password, from the user's input. The second parameter is the hashed password that you extract from the database.

Following, is the structure that I use for database extraction. It's OOP and uses correct coding conventions that you should try and learn before learning "procedural" style PHP, as this is the better way of coding.

```
class DatabaseConnect{

    protected
        $host, $user, $pass, $dbname, $con;

    public function __construct(){

        // Replace these with your database information. dbname is the name of the actual database, not the table.

        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->user = "root";
        $this->pass = "";
        $this->dbname = "test";
    }

    public function dbConnect(){
        try{
            $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user, $this->pass);
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function dbDisconnect(){
        $this->con = null;
    }
}

class Database extends DatabaseConnect{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getPassword($username){

        $sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?;";

        $this->dbConnect();

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $username); // This is the username that was passed to the method
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $this->dbDisconnect();

        return $results[0]["password"];
    }
}

// This is the code that uses the above classes. The classes can be kept in a separate file (and should be).
$database = new Database();
$passFromDatabase = $database->getPassword("pseud");
$passFromInput = $_POST["password"];

if(password_verify($passFromInput, $passFromDatabase)){
    echo "Passwords match";
}
```

The first class contains the information / methods to connect to the database. The second class has our method to get the password from the database, with a given username, and it extends the first class.

Then, below the classes, we are using them to get the data from the database.

Typically, on StackOverflow, people will refuse to do this kind of thing (giving you a full answer that you could very well just research) but I'd rather actually help :P. Just be aware, next time, that most people will refuse to help you.

Hope I helped.

Comment: sorry, my post must have been to vague. i want to know how i retrieve the password from the database and fill it in the variable $password

Comment: One moment then, will provide a full answer

Comment: There you go, hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use `password_verify` inside MySQL query.
 What you need to do is get the query the database for the record by email then compare the password hash returned from the database with the input password using **password_verify()**.

Follow the simple steps to verify the user.
1. Run the database query to get user by email to get the hashed password.
2. Verify this hashed password using **password_verify()**.

---

Reason we can't use **password_verify()** directly in MySQL queries is that password_hash() generates unique/different password each time you execute the **password_hash()** function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

you should probably connect DB first and then try to match hash
connecting database tutorial from link below

[PHP Select Data From MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

[login with php Hashing passwords](https://www.sitepoint.com/password-hashing-in-php/)

Comment: Please add the body of the code as links go stale after time.